# Porting Objective-C terminal apps from Mac OS X to Linux?

Tags: objective-c, c, linux, macos, cocoa

OK, here's the deal - nothing really crucial, just another compiler side-project of mine (yep, it's one of my hobbies, I admit it), but I was wondering :

- I'm using lex (Flex) and yacc (Bison), fully integrated
- the compiler's core (the program) is coded 100% in **Objective-C**, just using `Foundation`

So, this is the question :

- Once the program is up'n'running, how much effort will it require before porting it to some other *nix-based OS, Linux, etc. ?

Any advice?

---

**Sidenote :**

I've written almost 10 compilers exclusively in C/C++. However : I do love Objective-C and thought about using it as an experiment in this compiler creation project (actually an interpreter). The thing is that since I'm planning on using the resulting compiler on my Gentoo webserver, could this be a somewhat poor choice?

Comment: I don't believe there is any support for Foundation in the non-Apple world. They have released CF-Lite, but that won't help you.

Comment: http://www.gnustep.org: _The purpose of this project is to create a free and open version of the Cocoa (formerly known as NeXTSTEP/OpenStep) APIs and tools for as many platforms as possible. 

GNUstep provides a robust implementation of the AppKit and Foundation libraries as well as the development tools available on Cocoa [...]_

Comment: You might find life more compatible with Cocotron rather than gnustep: http://www.cocotron.org/ While Cocotron doesn't (yet) support UI on Linux, commandline code will be fine. A big difference being that you can (fairly) easily do the cross-compile right from within Xcode.

Comment: GNUstep, and using clang would be a better choice than gcc especially if you want Objective-C 2.0. You may also try to install and use gnustep-make on OSX, and write GNUmakefile which should be almost identical on both systems. See also, http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Cross_Compiling which I am not sure if it is still working, it used to work for me when I still have access to Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be much trouble. I made a simple program with some ssl stuff in Obj-C on an Ubuntu server. Here's my makefile:

```
FLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE

all:
    gcc -lobjc -lgnustep-base -lcrypt -lssl -I/usr/include/GNUstep geochatd.m -o geochatd
```

Comment: See my comment on the OP suggesting Cocotron in place of gnustep.